# Yii2: Show field/checkbox after checkbox is selected

Tags: checkbox, yii2

I have an ActiveForm in my _form view:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?> <?= $form->field($model, 'isInternal')->checkbox() ?> <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

('isInternal' is a boolean)

If the checkbox is selected I want to show another checkbox:

```
$form->field($model, 'activateReminder')->checkbox();
```

Is there a possibility? Maybe with JavaScript like this?

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'isInternal')->checkbox(['onclick' =>
 'showInternDetails()']) ?> 

<script>
 function showInternDetails() {
 $model->isInternal = 1;
 } 
</script>

<?php 
if($model->isInternal == true)
{
$form->field($model, 'activateReminder')->checkbox();
}
?>
```

Comment: You can do it with Javascript. You catch event when checkbox attribute value `checked` is changed and get element which you want to show and show it.

Comment: try using `when` and `whenClient`  within you model rules to make it work properly

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by JS:

```
<?php
$this->registerJs(
    "$('#myBox').on('change', function() { if($(this).is(":checked")){// Display your input...}else {// hide it} });",
    View::POS_READY
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `when` and `whenClient` options inside the model `rules` that you have declared so that it works when creating or updating both on the model end to require and show error to the user that he needs to select the value for the check-box and also to show and hide the `activateReminder` at the same time.

So go inside the model that you are using with this form and add a rule like below.

```
public function rules(){
    return [
      [['activateReminder'],'required','when'=>function($model){return ($model->isInternal);},
      'whenClient'=>'function(attribute,value){
           if($("#'.\yii\helpers\Html::getInputId($this, 'isInternal').'").val()===1){
              $("#'.\yii\helpers\Html::getInputId($this, 'activateReminder').'").show();
              return true;
           }else{
              $("#'.\yii\helpers\Html::getInputId($this, 'activateReminder').'").hide();
           }
      }']
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers!!
I have solved it as follows:

```
function isInternalOnClick(){ 
$('#isInternalCheckbox').on('change',function(){        showOrHideActivateReminder();});
}

function showOrHideActivateReminder() {
    if($('#isInternalCheckbox').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#hiddenActivateReminder').show()
    }
    else{
        $('#hiddenActivateReminder').hide();
    }    
} 

$(document).ready(function() {
    <?php 
            if($model->isInternal)
            {
                echo "
                showOrHideActivateReminder();
                ";
            }
            ?>
});
```

Comment: the answer i added handles at the model level you dont have to check for the `isInternal` value inside the view for that as Yii already provides you with these options